# Difficulty in appending elements to a list when using IO in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, io

I have a list of integers, I need to append elements to it at different times.

```
let xs =[]::[Int]
```

usually appending elements to this would be like:

```
1:xs
```

but when using IO in a function, it doesn't seem to work within a do block and gives errors, and

```
let xs = [1]
let xs=(2:xs)
```

results in an infinite list like [1,2,2,2,2,.....]
What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about lists in Haskell. The lists are always immutable, so there is no way to add new elements to an existing list. I.e. You can only create new lists.

So, accordingly, the `a:b` operator never adds an element to a list, but creates a new list where `a` is the first element, which is followed by the existing list `b`.

When you say:

```
let xs = 2 : xs
```

You are saying that `xs` is a list where the first element is `2` and the rest of the list is `xs` itself, which logically results in an infinite list of 2's. In the context of this question, it's irrelevant whether you are in the IO monad or not.

So given the above, you need to do something like

```
let xs1 = [1]
let xs2 = 2:xs1
let xs3 = 3:xs2
```

But of course, this is the same as simply doing

```
let xs3 = [3,2,1]
```

So you really need to give some more context on what kind of list you want to build and why.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, `let` bindings are recursive by default. So the two `xs` in the second line refer to themselves. The solution is to *not* shadow the `xs` binding:

```
let xs = [1]
let xs' = 2:xs
```

Remember that Haskell does not allow mutation. So the second `let` binding *does not* mean changing the value of `xs`--it means creating a new variable that just also happens to be called `xs`.

Just to clarify: `xs'` is completely separate from `xs`. Haskell lets you use `'` in variable names. `xs'` here could as easily be `xs2`. The `'` is pronounced "prime" (e.g. exes prime) and taken from math where things like `x`, `x'` and `x''` are common.

A side note: `:` *prepends* to a list; appending means putting the element on the end.

Also, your `let xs = 2:xs` results in `[2,2,2...]` rather than `[1,2,2,2...]`.

Comment: but, let xs' = 2:xs doesn't prepend 2 to the list :S

Comment: It creates a list `xs'` which is the result of prepending `2` to `xs`. Just use `xs'` instead of `xs` from that point on. If it weren't for recursive `let` bindings, your code would do the same thing except `xs'` would just be called `xs`.

Comment: but when I have `let xs = [1] , let xs' = 2:xs  , let xs' = 3:xs` those 3 lines xs will only output [3,1],  2 does not get prepended

Comment: I think the real issue is that you are not thinking about this in quite the right way. Each time you have a new `let`, you are creating a *new* variable, not changing a previous one. Haskell allows this new variable to have the same name (shadow) as an older variable, but you should not do this. If you really have to have separate steps like this, name each list something different.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if you *really* want to "assign" imperatively in the IO monad (which is what you seemed to be getting at), you could. You would use a mutable cell (a "reference"); which in the IO monad, would be `IORef`:

```
import Data.IORef

do xs <- newIORef [1]
   temp <- readIORef xs
   writeIORef xs (2 : temp)
```

However, doing so would be highly unidiomatic and you almost never want to write stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your list be recursive?

```
let xs = [1]
let foo=(2:xs) -- non-recursive
```